# submit specific value with javascript loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have something like this

```
<td class="standaard_klein" align="right">
  <div class="timereg<?php echo $TEL;?>" id="timereg<?php echo $TEL;?>">
    <i contenteditable><?php print(number_format($line2['WERKUREN'], 2, ',','')); ?>
    </i>
  </div>
</td>
<input type="hidden" name="hist_id" id="hist_id<?php echo $TEL;?>" value="<?php echo $line['ID'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" value="<?php echo $TEL;?>">
```

and this JS function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      var counter = document.getElementById('counter').value;
      $('#timereg'+counter).keypress(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 13){
            var x = document.getElementById('timereg'+counter).textContent;
            var y = document.getElementById('hist_id'+counter).value;
            $('#timereg'+counter).load('change_timereg.php?newtime=' + x + '&user=<?php echo $_SESSION['loginid'];?>&hist_id='+ y);
            }
       });

</script>
```

but it get only first "counter" element. How can I modify function to get specific "counter"? $TEL is counter value that I want to get. (usually it's $i but here $TEL were used).

SOLUTION: jsfiddle.net/qmtGK THANK TO Jacob Amerz

Comment: is the PHP variable `$TEL`, and all the HTML in your first snippet part of a loop? if so, you have duplicate ID's, which is a no-no

Comment: first `id` should be unique in a document, so don't use `id` for the `counter` instead use a class

Comment: Yes it's part of the loop...so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you write

```
 <input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" value="<?php echo $TEL;?>">
```

Not only once but inside a loop, you use the same id for many elements, which won't work.

May i suggest a different approach? Give each div related counter and attach a shared class

```
<div class="timereg<?php echo $TEL;?> shared_class" related-counter="counter<?php echo $tel;?>" id="timereg<?php echo $TEL;?>">
    <i contenteditable><?php print(number_format($line2['WERKUREN'], 2, ',','')); ?>
    </i>
</div>


<input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter<?php echo $tel;?>" value="<?php echo $TEL;?>">
```

and then the js:

```
    $('.shared_class').keypress(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
           // ... whatever you want to do
           related_counter = $(this).attr("related-counter");               
           $("#"+related_counter).load('change_timereg.php?newtime=' + x + '&user=<?php echo $_SESSION['loginid'];?>&hist_id='+ y);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZrLBM/ actually it's more like a snippet, but you'll see what I did. Thank' for help

Comment: It because you're trying to use `related_counter` before you got it with `.attr()` , also , your fiddle isn't using jQuery in newtworks & extensions . Anyway, here's a working one: http://jsfiddle.net/qmtGK/ , note that i replaced the php code with some dummy text

Answer (score 0):

The problems is you are reading the value of counter only once at the page load.
What you need to do is when the `enter key` is pressed, you need to find out the corresponding counter value.

```
$('#timereg'+counter).keypress(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        var counter = $(this).closest('td').find(':input[name="counter"]').val();
        var x = document.getElementById('timereg'+counter).textContent;
        var y = document.getElementById('hist_id'+counter).value;
        $('#timereg'+counter).load('change_timereg.php?newtime=' + x + '&user=<?php echo $_SESSION['loginid'];?>&hist_id='+ y);
    }
});
```